# variable is NaN in method of mobx class(observable - mobx)

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to update counter whoch observable variable, and watch the values in component, swhen I click the increment button, this.counter is NaN always and couldnt understand why. 
component:

```
@observer
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    const counter = this.props.appState;
    return (
        <div className={styles.description}>
          <button onClick={counter.increment.bind(this)}>+</button>
```

Mobx class;

```
class AppState{
    @observable counter=0

   increment(){
       debugger //its null..
        this.counter++;
    }
}
export default AppState
```

mainjs:

```
import AppState from './AppState'
...
var appState = new AppState

ReactDOM.render(
  <App appState={appState}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that you need to keep a sharp tongue when it comes to what `this` refers to. There's no `counter` field in `App`, and that's what you end up trying refer to when you write `bind(this)`.

Try `<button onClick={() => counter.increment()}>+</button>`.